# Ubuntu boot cd confusion

Tags: windows, cd

If I burn the ISO to a CD on Windows 7 using their burner or whatever burner is required, can i boot the cd on mac and install ubuntu?

I dont want to use disk utility or any mac burning tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use the amd64+mac images available in cdimage.ubuntu.com.
Take http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1/release/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64+mac.iso for example.

Comment: Thankyou, will do. But if i burn it using a windows burner, it will work with mac, yeah?

Comment: Yes it would. Do it!

Comment: Fortunately, the iso format is not OS specific :-)

Comment: Yes:) Anyway, upvote it if you like:)

Comment: I would but I don't have 15 rep sorry. I'll bookmark this page and upvote when I earn some rep:)! ill get back to you once i've tried it

Comment: Please mark it as answer using the green tick